# Return HTML file using Adonisjs Router

Tags: html, reactjs, routes, adonis.js

I am creating one web application using AdonisJs in backend and ReactJs in frontend.
While integrating both frameworks i am struggling to return index.html file of ReactJs on '/' route path from AdonisJs, since AdonisJs is supporting edge.js for view.

Is there any solution in AdonisJs similar to expressjs returning HTML file as given below

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(9000);
```

Currently my AdonisJs route returning edge file like,

```
Route.any('*', ({view}) =>  view.render('index'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change template file extensions in config file which resides on `config/app.js`.

```javascript
{
  static: {
    extensions: ['html']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to be running Adonis by motorcycle stack, if using only as API it will only return JSON rendered responses

now if you are in an Adonis stack installation just use the view object that looks like this:

```
Route.get('/page', ({ view }) => {
    view.render('name_of_view')
})
```